# GNU Icecat always on UTC

Tags: gnu-icecat

I am on Debian bullseye, and I use GNU Icecat as my main browser.

It is my favorite browser, but it irks me that its time zone is always UTC, though I am in a different one. I see this because some websites detect my browser's time zone and compare it with the account time zone.

---

I tried running it while passing an environment variable:

`TZ='US/Pacific' icecat`

I ran the following in the JS Console:

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`

The offset returned by IceCat is always 0. Firefox returns it as per the time zone, but I am not sure how - it doesn't seem to obey the TZ variable either.

---

Is this a bug with Icecat itself? A privacy-preservation measure? A configuration error? <strike>The Debian package?</strike> *I don't think it's the Debian package, because it was not installed via APT.*

In any case, I would like to have the proper time zone returned. How do I fix it?

In case it's relevant, my build version is `60.3.0esr (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To report the correct timezone, go to `about:config` and toggle `privacy.resistFingerprinting` to `false` then restart. So yes, this does appear to be a privacy-preserving measure.

Note that togging the setting will immediately affect calls to `new Date().toString()` in all tabs making them show the correct timezone, but `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` doesn't appear to report the correct offset in all tabs until after restarting.

See [this discussion on the Icecat mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnuzilla/2019-06/msg00010.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will also search the mailing list from now on, and maybe post what I think is worth it over.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on IceCatMobile

Comment: It used to work but stopped working again for me.